# Restore deleted folders on ext4

Tags: ext4, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted two folders from my home directory and I want to recover them. I don't want to use testdisk or ext4magic (they just don't work for me and are really annoying). Also I have 400gb free on my main hard drive and I am using ext4.

Comment: Take another undelete program that not annoying you. R-undelete is ok for you?

Comment: Please give R-Studio Undelete a try: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000 if you run out of options. It's one of the best file undelete utilities out there. Not free but totally worth it.

Comment: There is free version https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/

Comment: Just don't install it on the disk from which you want you recover the deleted files

Comment: The longer you leave your system running the more likely it is that your deleted files will get overwritten